# OS X / Windows bootcamp, Wi-Fi drops on OS X only

Tags: macos, networking, wireless-networking, boot-camp

While I know there can be a vast sea of different explanations to this matter, I am trying to figure out why my Wi-Fi keeps dropping on OS X but not on my Windows(bootcamp)-partition.

Symptoms:
 - I suddenly notice the network to be unresponsive in OS X. This can happen everything from once every 3 minutes to 3 times a day. No obvious pattern.
 - The signal always shows as full, yet the network is unreachable, both through browsers and by pinging. 
 - After restarting the Wi-Fi using the dropdown-menu for Wi-Fi in the upper right and selecting `Turn Wi-Fi On/Off`, the connectivity returns almost immediately.

On Windows I have yet to experience this issue, thus I have concluded it is most likely not a hardware problem. However, I only use my Windows partition for online-gaming, so I thought that perhaps the network is dropping on OS X due to the network-adapter not being constantly active, but it's just a thought.

What does it sound like might be the issue here?

**Update 1:**
I wasn't able to find information on which frequency was used, but I included pretty much everything else. If you know where to find it, let me know.

**Router information**

> Router model: D-Link DIR-501
>   Wireless Channel: 10   
>   **Wireless Network Settings**
>   Wireless Mode: Wireless Router
>   Enable Wireless: On
>   Enable Auto Channel Selection: Off
>   Transmission Rate: Best(auto)    (Mbit/s)
>
>   WMM Enable: On    (Wireless QoS)
>   Enable Hidden Wireless: Off (Also called the SSID Broadcast)
>   **Advanced Wireless Settings**
>   Transmit Power: 100%
>   Beacon Period: 100 (msec, range:20~1000, default:100) 
>   RTS Threshold: 2346 (range: 256~2346, default:2346)
>   Fragmentation: 2346 (range: 1500~2346, default:2346, even number only)
>   DTIM Interval: 1 (range: 1~255, default:1)
>   Preamble Type: [Short Preamble]   Long Preamble
>   CTS Mode : None   Always  [Auto]
>   Wireless Mode: 802.11 Mixed(n/g/b)
>   Band Width: [20MHz] 20/40MHz(Auto)
>   STBC: Enable   [Disabled]
>   20/40MHz Coexist: Enable   [Disabled]
>   Short Guard Interval: On

**OS X Network Report**

> **Current Network**
>   SSID: Vordhosbn:
>   PHY Mode: 802.11n
>   BSSID:  b8:a3:86:bc:be:dc
>   Channel:  10
>   Country Code: US
>   Network Type: Infrastructure
>   Security: WPA2 Personal
>   Signal / Noise: -35 dBm / -82 dBm
>   Transmit Rate:  73
>   MCS Index:  7
>
> **Wi-Fi adapter information**
>   Software Versions:
>   CoreWLAN: 4.3.2 (432.47)
>   CoreWLANKit:  3.3.2 (332.36)
>   Menu Extra: 9.3.2 (932.35)
>   System Information: 9.0 (900.8)
>   IO80211 Family: 6.3 (630.35)
>   Diagnostics:  3.0 (300.40)
>   AirPort Utility:  6.3.2 (632.3)
>   Interfaces:
>   en0:
>   Card Type:  AirPort Extreme  (0x14E4, 0xEF)
>   Firmware Version: Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.22)
>   MAC Address:  b8:f6:b1:1b:26:1d
>   Locale: ETSI
>   Country Code: US
>   Supported PHY Modes:  802.11 a/b/g/n
>   Supported Channels: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 36, 40, 44, 48, 52, 56, 60, 64, 100, 104, 108, 112, 116, 120, 124, 128, 132, 136, 140, 149, 153, 157, 161, 165
>   Wake On Wireless: Supported
>   AirDrop:  Supported
>   Status: Connected

Comment: Couple questions.  Which 802.11 mode are you using?  What 802.11 does your wireless adapter support?  What frequency are you using (2.4Ghz or 5.0Ghz )?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean, but something from my OSX system report: en0(my WiFi interface): `Supported PHY Modes: 802.11 a/b/g/n`.
The network I am hosting with the router: `PHY Mode: 802.11n`

Comment: If it was a mode-compatibility issue, it wouldn't work in Windows either, would it?

Comment: No;  If you were connecting to the 802.11n network in Windows using 802.11n and 80.11g on OS X the loss of connectivity could be explained.  I really wanted an update to the question with **all** the information I asked for.  **The fact it can happen ever 3 minutes tells me there is something going on.**

Comment: Thanks. I will happily provide all the information, but how do I find it? Should I post the system-report on Wi-Fi, or do you have some terminal-commands I could use?

Comment: You can provide the information for the router, the frequency information, and what you have already said about the adapter answers the last question I had.  I also need to know which channel your using.

Comment: Added some details.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known user issue on some Macs. I had it a few times. I haven't seen any official recognition from Apple, not that I had the patience to check hundreds of threads.

Check [the Internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=random%20wireless%20drops%20macbook).